# Base change for the cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $f: X\longrightarrow \operatorname{Spec} A$ be a morphism and $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$, flat over $\operatorname{Spec} A$. If $M$ is an $A$-algebra then, as in Hartshrone III $\S 12$ there is a natural mapping
$$H^0(X, \mathcal{F})\otimes M \longrightarrow H^0(X, \mathcal{F}\otimes_A M).$$
I am trying to understand for any $x\in H^0(X, \mathcal{F})$ what is the image of $x\otimes 1$.
My guess is the following.

Since the sheaf $\mathcal{F}\otimes_A M$ is exactly the sheaf $\mathcal{F}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} f^*\widetilde{M}$, so we can define the above mapping
\begin{align}
H^0(X, \mathcal{F})\otimes M &\longrightarrow H^0(X, \mathcal{F}\otimes_A M) \ as\\
x\otimes 1 & \longrightarrow (x_P\otimes 1)_{P\in X}.
\end{align}

My reason is the following, since we know that for any presheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, the global section of the sheafification $\mathcal{F}^+$ is given by
$$\mathcal{F}^+(X)= \{(x_P\in \mathcal{F}_P)_{P\in X};  \  \mathrm{with\ some\ compatible\ condition}\}.$$
So, we can define the mapping as above.

Comment: What is $Y\hspace{0pt}$?

Comment: Sorry, Y = Spec A, A is a Noetherian ring.